# Django FilePathField doesn't work with relative path

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles, django-media

There is a model `Language`. Language objects creates Admin through `Django-admin`. They have to choose from dropdown menu appropriate flag file.

The problem is that there is not flag to choice when I deploy project.

Since static files are being collected before deploy, I tried to set this path:

```
flag = models.FilePathField(path='static/img/flags/550px',default='')
```

But as you can see, it can't find anything.

[image]

I can choose from flags if I do this:

```
flag = models.FilePathField(path=settings.BASE_DIR+'/static/img/flags/550px',default='')
```

But then it doesn't work just calling `language.flag` because it returns absolute path.

```
<img src = "{{ language.flag }}">
```

produce this:

```
<img src="/home/django/MyProject/static/img/flags/550px/ar.png">
```

The only solution which comes to my mind is to create a property which strips `path` cutting "/home/django/MyProject/" but I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Is there a better way?

```
class Language(models.Model):
    shortcut = models.CharField(max_length=40,
                                help_text=_('Shortcut of the language'),
                                unique=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=40,
                            help_text=_('Name of the language'),
                            unique=True, verbose_name=_("Language"))

    flag = models.FilePathField(path='static/img/flags/550px',default='/static/img/icons/check-icon.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

EDIT:

Admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import  Language

admin.site.register(Language)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FilePathField.path
>   Required. The **absolute** filesystem path to a directory from which this >FilePathField should get its choices. Example: "/home/images".

Emphasis mine.

And when you use an absolute path here, your template really does produce a relative path I can't tell you what that is because that path you have set in the FilePathField and the path that you claim to get contradict each other. But i can assure you that the template will give a relative path.

Not sure, if it's a bug (probably is) but your admin is saving the full path in the flag object instead of just the relative path. So I guess using a property is one option

```
 @property
 flag_path(self):
     return self.flag.replace(settings.BASE_DIR,'')
```

The other option is to overide the admin save model method to do the stripping at that point

Comment: No, when I do {{ language.flag }} in template I get /home/django/myproject/static/... but I need /static/.... so I dont understand what to do.

Comment: First fix the inconsistencies in your question. Then add the admin. I suspect you might be having a problem there

Comment: What inconsistencies do you mean? I've corrected a path. The problem is that FilePathField allows me to choose from flags if there is an absolute way set (BASE_DIR + /static/....). But when I choose from flags this way, then, in template, {{ language.flag }} returns /home/django/myproject/static/... but I need just /static/....

Comment: I've added an admin.py but there is nothing except admin.site.register(Language)

Comment: please see the upate

Comment: It is a [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6896) against relative path of FilePathField. And a [proposed module](https://bitbucket.org/alexhayes/django-relativefilepathfield). I don't know if this module is uptodate

Answer (score 0):

A design decision was made by Django to not give the option of storing a relative path in `FilePathField` (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6896). Instead, @alexhayes kindly provided a `RelativeFilePathField` that stores relative paths, and otherwise works the same as `FilePathFIeld`: https://bitbucket.org/alexhayes/django-relativefilepathfield/src/master/.

Very briefly, you:

```
pip install django-relativefilepathfield
```

Then,you use it in your model like:

```
from relativefilepathfield.fields import RelativeFilePathField

class Language(models.Model):
    ...
    absflagpath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'/static/img/flags/550px')
    flag = RelativeFilePathField(path=absflagpath, default='check-icon.png')
```

Admin works like it should, the choices being displayed and selected in the UI are the very same things as what's stored in the DB (!). `language.flag` returns just the relative part. `Language.absflagpath` is a class attribute/variable that is not stored in the DB, and returns the **absolute** path that the stored relative paths are relative to. Note that the default parameter for `flag` is relative.